# Blazor WebAssembly client side routing: Tenant name in browser location

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly app and would like to identify the tenant from the URI - and also display the tenant alias in the URI of the browsers address bar at all time.

At the server side I've added a middleware which identifies the tenant from the request URI path and manages the routing - which works great so far.

But at the client side I just don't get it: When I navigate to `https://domain/tenant`, everything is fine, the app starts and displays a page. But when I click on a link and navigate to any other page, the URI in the browsers address bar looks like `https://domain/page_route` - instead of `https://domain/tenant/page_path`.

So my question is: How can I intercept the routing in a way that the tenant alias (which comes from let's say `Tenant.Current.Alias`) is visible in the browsers address bar always?

Example:

- The user calls `https://domain`, which uses the default tenant `tenant`
- The user clicks on a link which routes to `page_path`, which should result in the URI `https://domain/tenant/page_path` then

Another example:

- The user calls `https://domain/tenant`
- The user clicks on a link which routes to `page_path`, which should result in the URI `https://domain/tenant/page_path` then

By the way, for API requests I've modified the `HttpClient` injection at the client and changed the `BaseAddress` to the URI which includes the tenant alias. This works for API requests, but of course it doesn't affect the URI which is being displayed in the browsers address bar.

**UPDATE**: For now I came to the conclusion, that I need to edit all page routes, and there's no way like URI rewriting at the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I did it: The trick is to modify the `base` tag in the bootstrapping `index.html` so it includes the tenant alias.

For this I deleted the `index.html`, created a `Index.cshtml` as new server page and changed the default routing to use the `Index.cshtml`, before looking for a `index.html`. Then it was required to redirect a browser, which calls an URI without the tenant alias in the request URI path.

At the client I updated the navigation to use `@("/"+tenantAlias+"/anything")` as href. In the Razor pages I could remove the tenant alias from the routes, since the navigation manager uses the `base` href and combines it with a page route.

This is way more complicated as at the server side, but it seems to be the correct way, since it's not possible to modify the URI which is used by the `NavigationManager`, and this base URI is initialized only once during bootstrapping (that's why a browser redirect is required).

**UPDATE for .NET 8**:

Since .NET 8 changed a few things, the whole thing is a bit more easy now. Posting a complete demo project seems to be too much - but you can find one online now:

https://github.com/nd1012/Demo/tree/ASP.NET-Tenant-URI?tab=readme-ov-file

The latest commit shows the whole working solution - and these changes were required to be applied to the plain project in order to make it working:

https://github.com/nd1012/Demo/commit/9c9fad84253dc05dc7f4de29d017b54091a73e7b

Comment: Hi.
Any chance to get an example of this?

Comment: @M_B With .NET 8 some things have changed - so I updated the solution with links to a working demo on GitHub. Hope it helps!